# Is the batsman run-out if ball in contact with the lying stump

Tags: cricket

I have question regarding run out controversy which happened today in our teams play. We had just one stump on the non-striker end which fell off(due to wind) when batsman launched for 2nd run. Bowler caught the ball and touched the stump(which was lying on the ground) with ball while holding in his hand(batsman was short of crease). Is the batsman out or not?

Comment: I presume you mean "bail" instead of "stump".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the batsman is not out. [Law 29.1.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-29-the-wicket-is-down/) defines the situations in which the wicket is considered to be put down:

> 29.1.1 The wicket is put down if a bail is completely removed from the top of the stumps, or a stump is struck out of the ground,
>
> 29.1.1.1 by the ball,
>
> 29.1.1.2 by the striker’s bat
>
> [ some other less common occurrences ]
>
> 29.1.1.6 The wicket is also put down if a fielder strikes or pulls a stump out of the ground in the same manner.

Hence what the bowler should have done was strike the remaining stumps so that either the remaining bail was removed or a stump was removed from the ground; touching the stump which was *already* on the ground does not constitute putting the wicket down and so the batsman cannot be out.